# java.lang.object cannot be cast to Data.Links when copying code from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, casting

I try to move a project from eclipse to android studio and the same code gives me an error:

```
java.lang.object cannot be cast to Data.Links
```

On Eclipse its works well.

The code and android studio screen shoot attach in order to see the overal picture of the project [code and android studio screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9M46.jpg)

I also attach the code

```
    package nirtzin.com.pushbots;

import Data.Links;
import utils.IO;
import utils.Internet;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int menuOpenOrClose = 0;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://nirtzin.com.pushbots/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://nirtzin.com.pushbots/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }

    class Layout {
        public Layout() {
            slideMenu = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlideMenu);
            view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
            menuly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuLinearLayout);
            bmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmenu);
        }

        FrameLayout slideMenu;
        WebView view;
        LinearLayout menuly;
        Button bmenu;


    }

    class Event {
        public Event() {
            l.bmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (menuOpenOrClose == 0) {
                        OpenMenu();

                    } else {
                        CloseMenu();

                    }

                }


            });


            l.menuly.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

                                        {

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                                switch (event.getAction()) {
                                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                                        d.startX = event.getX();
                                                        d.startY = event.getY();
                                                        return true;
                                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                        d.endX = event.getX();
                                                        d.endY = event.getY();

                                                        d.deltaX = d.endX - d.startX;
                                                        d.deltaY = d.endY - d.startY;

                                                        //לבדוק מה הכיוון העיקרי
                                                        if (Math.abs(d.deltaX) > Math.abs(d.deltaY)) {
                                                            //תנועה על ציר האיקס
                                                            if (Math.abs(d.deltaX) >= d.SENSETIVITY) {
                                                                //בדיקת כיוון

                                                                if (d.deltaX > 0) {
                                                                    //ימינה
                                                                    CloseMenu();
                                                                } else {
                                                                    //שמאלה
                                                                    OpenMenu();
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            //תנועה על ציר הוואי
                                                            if (Math.abs(d.deltaY) >= d.SENSETIVITY) {
                                                                //בדיקת כיוון

                                                                if (d.deltaY > 0) {
                                                                    //למטה

                                                                } else {
                                                                    //למעלה

                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        return true;
                                                }
                                                ;


                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }

            );

            // bmenu.setOnClickListener(new BMenuClickListener());
        }


    }

    class generalData {
        public generalData() {
            // geting screen full size
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
            screenHeight = size.y;

            startX = 0;
            startY = 0;
            endX = 0;
            endY = 0;
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = 0;
            SENSETIVITY = 100;


        }

        int screenWidth, screenHeight;
        float startX, startY, endX, endY, deltaX, deltaY;
        int SENSETIVITY;
        String link[][];

    }

    //variables
    String fileName = "menulinks.xml";
    String urlStr = "http://bsn.co.il/applications_menu_links.xml";
    Context c;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// init the pushbots to enable it

        l = new Layout();
        e = new Event();
        d = new generalData();

        //load my menu links
        try {
            Internet.DownloadFiles(this, urlStr, fileName);
            Links links = (Links) IO.load(this, Links.class, fileName);
            /*dynamical build of the menu */
            if (links != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < links.links.size(); i++) {
                    MenuItem v = new MenuItem(this, null);
                    v.setmenuline(links.links.get(i).getName());
                    v.setUrl(links.links.get(i).getWebLink());
                    l.menuly.addView(v);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);

        l.slideMenu.setTranslationX(d.screenWidth);

        c = getBaseContext();


        // default url
        String url = "http://app.bsn.co.il/node/9058";
        l.view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //chack if this is new load or its need to load the page from the menu url
       /* Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


        if (extras != null)
        {
            //String newurl = extras.getString("articleLink");
            String newurl = "app.bsn.co.il/node/7787";
            l.view.loadUrl(newurl);

        }
        else {
            l.view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        */
        l.view.loadUrl(url);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    Layout l;
    Event e;
    generalData d;


    public void OpenMenu() {

        //l.slideMenu.setTranslationX(d.screenWidth-300);
        menuOpenOrClose = 1;
        ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(l.slideMenu, "translationX", d.screenWidth, d.screenWidth - 400);
        translationX.setDuration(200);
        translationX.start();

        //l.slideMenu.animate().x(d.endX).setDuration(0).start();
    }


    public void CloseMenu() {

        //l.slideMenu.setTranslationX(d.screenWidth);
        menuOpenOrClose = 0;
        ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(l.slideMenu, "translationX", d.screenWidth - 400, d.screenWidth);
        translationX.setDuration(200);
        translationX.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


        if (extras != null) {
            String newurl = extras.getString("articleLink");
            //String newurl = "app.bsn.co.il/node/7787";
            l.view.loadUrl(newurl);

        } else {
            l.view.loadUrl("http://app.bsn.co.il/node/9058");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
/*
    //  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
    }
*/




   /* private class BMenuClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator translationX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( l.slideMenu, "translationX", 400, 0);
            translationX.setDuration(500);
            translationX.start();
        }
    }

    private class TaskListner implements LinkDataTask.Listener {
        @Override
        public void onResponce(Data data) {

        }
    } */
}
```

Comment: Please show us the imports of the class where you are having trouble.

Comment: added the whole code with the imports

Comment: Don't add the full code, show a [mcve]. Also add your Data.Links and IO classes

Comment: this is what i did at start but then i got asked for the imports. how to add the 2 classes (data and IO) to this post ?

Comment: hi, i still fighting with that cast think.
when i debug it i notice that the object that i casting is null.

Comment: hi, i still fighting with that cast think.
when i debug it i notice that the object that i casting is null.